# Saving html to csv and opening with Excel

Tags: c#, html, csv

I'm trying to save data from the database into a csv file. My problem is that some of the data is in html and when opening the csv in excel the data is not formatted correctly. I need to keep the html as is and I cannot edit it. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: The purpose of this is to view what content is being displayed on a certain webpage. For a lot of the older web pages html was being stored in the database. So whatever is in the database I need to print out into a cell exactly as it is in the database

Comment: @tjarratt The above response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Don't send a CSV.

If your destination is Excel, then just export the data into excel.

Look at http://epplus.codeplex.com/